# How to add apostrophes around strings from an imploded array in a MySQL IN statement?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, implode

I have the following array in PHP : `3D, 瑪丹娜, 電影, 情報, 大獨裁`

My SQL query is the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news 
WHERE tagkey IN (3D, 瑪丹娜, 電影, 情報, 大獨裁)";
```

But this query gives an error: `Query failed`.

I need to add apostrophes, but how can I change

```
`3D, 瑪丹娜, 電影, 情報, 大獨裁`
```

to

```
`'3D', '瑪丹娜', '電影', '情報', '大獨裁'`
```

?

So the query would be like:

```
$query = "select * FROM news WHERE tagkey IN ('3D','瑪丹娜','電影','情報','大獨裁') ";
```

My current PHP code:

```
$tag_array = array($line["tagkey"]);
$tag_str = implode(" ", array($line["tagkey"]));
echo $tag_str;
$query = "select * FROM news WHERE tagkey IN ($tag_str)";
```

**update 2012/06/15
**sorry:now i change my Vhost . this script error..**

this:
Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: The first argument, 
'apply_quotes', should be either NULL or a valid callback in

```
$list = explode(',', $line["tagkey"]);
$list = array_map('apply_quotes', $list);
```

Warning: join() [function.join]: Bad arguments. in

```
$query = "select * FROM news 
      WHERE tagkey IN (" . join(',', $list) . ") ";
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: You want to remov 3D from array ...everytime ???

Comment: want to IN ('3d','瑪丹娜','電影','情報','大獨裁')

Comment: Don't even forget to escape what you put into your query. `mysql_real_escape_string()` is what you need with the old `mysql_` functions.

Comment: sorry:now i change my Vhost . this script error..
this:
Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: The first argument, <br>'apply_quotes', should be either NULL or a valid callback in
$list = explode(',', $line["tagkey"]);
$list = array_map('apply_quotes', $list);

Warning: join() [function.join]: Bad arguments. in

$query = "select * FROM news 
   WHERE tagkey IN (" . join(',', $list) . ") ";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Misread the earlier question.

You have to escape each individual item in your array before you use it in the query:

```
function apply_quotes($item)
{
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($item) . "'";
}

$list = array('3D', '瑪丹娜','電影','情報','大獨裁');

$list = array_map('apply_quotes', $list);
```

Then, to construct the query:

```
$query = "select * FROM news WHERE upordown = 1 AND tagkey IN (" . 
    join(',', $list) . 
    ") AND id <> $id ORDER BY udate DESC";
```

If all your items are inside a string instead of an array, you have to turn it into an array first:

```
$list = explode(',', '3D,瑪丹娜,電影,情報,大獨裁');
```

I'm assuming that you're using `mysql_` functions; if not, let me know :)

Comment: i got this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Comment: Must be older PHP version then :) will update later but in the meantime you can consider another answer.

Answer (score 3):

[`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) lets you call a function on every element of an array.

```
$tag_array = array_map ( function($var) {
  return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($var) . "'";
}, $tag_array );
```

But I suggest you use prepared statements ([PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of the soon deprecated `mysql_` functions).

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear, but try like this ;

```
$tag_array = array($line["tagkey"]);
$tag_str = implode(" ", array($line["tagkey"]));
echo $tag_str;
$query = "select * FROM news WHERE upordown = 1 AND tagkey IN ('".$tag_str."') AND id <> '".$id."' ORDER BY udate DESC ";
```

Comment: What he want is quote every element, your way will still be error.

Comment: get it error :
select * FROM news WHERE upordown = 1 AND tagkey IN ('3D,瑪丹娜,電影,情報,大獨裁') AND id <> '39' ORDER BY udate DESC